# How to retrieve radio button value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i want to retrieve the value of radio button, here how they look

```
"<td width=70% align=left class=WizardBodyFont><input type=radio name=gender id=gender value=""M"" checked>Male" & vbcrlf
        g_strBodyText = g_strBodyText & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name=gender id=gender value=""F"">Female</td></tr>"
```

I'm trying to retrieve the radio button value based on ID like below in my javascript & its not working.

```
 gendernode = fraWizard.document.frmWizard.getElementById("gender");
```

If i try to get the values based on Tag name its working fine

```
var txts = fraWizard.document.frmWizard.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

How to retrieve the value by ID.

Comment: hi, vote -1 can u pls explain?

Comment: I think `var value = document.getElementById("gender").value;` should do the trick

Comment: What is `fraWizard.document.frmWizard` supposed to be? If there are any iframes or similar in play, then you should tell us. Otherwise, that syntax makes little sense.

Comment: **ids need to be unique**

Comment: IDs have to be unique within an HTML document, you can not give both input fields the same one.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value using **getElementsByName**:

```
gender_value = document.getElementsByName("gender").value;
```

Comment: Hi, its not working. If i try this, fraWizard.document.frmWizard.getElementsByTagName("input"), i m getting all inputs, but if i try by ID. its failing

Comment: I changed my answer .. sorry.

You can user "getElementsByName" instead.

I think it should work.

Comment: And if you can use jQuery, it simply:

gender_value = $("input[name=gender]:checked").val();

Comment: ok, thanks i will try.. thanks